# Casting object created with Sys.time()

Tags: r, performance, time, performance-testing

I'm measuring the performance of several function in nested foreach loops, in order to do that

```
start <- Sys.time()
<corpus of function>
end <- Sys.time()
diff_time = end - start
```

The problem is that afterwords the object assumes the class "*diff_time*" and i've trouble plotting it with ggplot2.

It is possibile that some simulation that are quicker than others will have the suffix **sec** and others **mins**? If that occurs, how can i avoid these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the units when converting the *difftime* to *numeric*.

```
t = difftime(time1 = "2016-01-02 01:00:00", time2 = "2016-01-02 00:30:00")
t
# Time difference of 30 mins

as.numeric(t, units = "secs")
# [1] 1800
```

Comment: I guess i should power off the pc now, too tired. Thanks, this is it!